# Cocoa Touch drop down box on iPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am implementing an iPad app that needs to make use of a drop down box or something to filter items in a tableview.

Can anyone suggest a control?  I can't use the picker view (because you can't adjust height) and the segment view can't hold enough items.

Comment: Why not use the UIPicker view in an actionsheet? (Or other similar modal dialog.) That said, wouldn't isn't a Search Controller more appropriate for filtering a UITableView?

Comment: Have you searched SO for "iphone dropdown"? It will give plenty results.

Comment: You don't want a drop-down, that's not an iOS control. As @middaparka noted, you want a UIPickerView or a Search Controller.

Comment: If you want to search something in UITableView you have to use Search Controller

Comment: @middaparka - action sheet sounds perfect tks! if you can just answer the post and I will mark it as correct

Comment: @TheLearner I've added a suitably generic answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, I'd be tempted to use a UIPicker view in an [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). (Or other similar modal dialog.)

That said, it might be more appropriate to use a [Search Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to filter the UITableView. (Really depends on the application.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could just use a Search Controller to me, is your data categorisable? You could be better off just creating a hierarchy and navigating through it using a Navigation Controller to move between tableviews.

Comment: I have 4 columns in my tableview each represents an attribute of the items in the tableview.  So I want my user to be able to switch easily between items with certain attributes.  ActionSheet / modal dialog sounds interesting

Comment: Cool, you could also try using adding a Tab Bar and using that as the switcher.